# Query parameters of the get URL using aiohttp from python3.5

Tags: python

```
async def method(request):
    ## here how to get query parameters
    param1 = request.rel_url.query['name']
    param2 = request.rel_url.query['age']
    return web.Response(text=str(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', "/sample", method)    

    web.run_app(app,host='localhost', port=3000)
```

The above code is running in python 3.6. I need to extract the query parameter values (xyz & xy) from the sample URL `http://localhost.com/sample?name=xyz&age=xy`. I Tried with `req.rel_url.query` and also with `request.query_string`. It was giving only the first parameter value xyz, but I was not getting xy (age) which was the second parameter in the query.

How can I get both the query values?

Comment: Here are some changes to my snippet.

Comment: 1. localhost was changed to my machine IP , so in query http://<IP Adress>:3000/sample?name=xyz&age=xy                                                             2. business logic for result was not added in the snippet. Since I was failing in request.rel_url.query['age'].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have few errors here.

1. `result` is not defined in your function. You get params right way, but then error occurs as `result` is not defined
2. You're targeting `localhost.com`, not sure how that is set on your machine, but it shouldn't work.

So, here is working example:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def method(request):
    ## here how to get query parameters
    param1 = request.rel_url.query['name']
    param2 = request.rel_url.query['age']
    result = "name: {}, age: {}".format(param1, param2)
    return web.Response(text=str(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', "/sample", method)

    web.run_app(app,host='localhost', port=11111)
```

then you can try: http://localhost:11111/sample?name=xyz&age=xy and it is working.

Comment: I tried with the above snippet. I was getting an error of   KeyError: "Key not found: 'age'". The business logic for result I have not added. But the issue I was facing was, I was not able to read the second parameter value(In this case it was age )

Comment: Local host was changed to my machine IP address

Comment: `return web.Response(text=str(result))` str function is not required, because format method returns the string already.

Comment: Understand this is a old post, but this is exactly what I am trying to do and it works! BUT how do I stop web.run_app once it returns the result? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, this was long time ago. You can check documentation to see if it helps:
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#graceful-shutdown

Answer (score 2):

Quick example:

```
async def get_handler(self, request):

    param1 = request.rel_url.query.get('name', '')
    param2 = request.rel_url.query.get('age', '')

    return web.Response(text=f"Name: {param1}, Age: {param2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The topic is old but I have encountered a similar problem: turns out the issue didn't come from the server but the client:

- `curl http://localhost.com/sample?name=xyz&age=xy` was indeed sending only the first parameter.
- However `curl "http://localhost.com/sample?name=xyz&age=xy"` gave the desired result.

Make sure the parameters are well sent with the request