# AIOHTTP, can't read multiple parameters from request

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I try to read multiple parameters `lat` and `lon` from my request using `request.rel_url.query["lat"]` and `request.rel_url.query["lon"]`, respectively (following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851262/9710338)).

When debugging, `query` has only one element, the second parameter is not read correctly.

The call:

```
$ curl -i -X GET 127.0.0.1:8000/test?lat=47.659049&lon=9.166003
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 55
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 06:49:15 GMT
Server: Python/3.8 aiohttp/3.6.2
Connection: close

500 Internal Server Error

Server got itself in trouble
```

The python error:

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lorenz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 418, in start
    resp = await task
  File "/home/lorenz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 458, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "/home/lorenz/Documents/copernicus-service/topography/topography_server.py", line 199, in handle_copernicus
    lon = request.rel_url.query["lon"]
KeyError: 'lon'
```

What's the reason for this, and how can I read the 2nd parameter correctly?

Comment: Use single quotes (or double quotes) for the URL if it includes ampersand: `curl -i -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?lat=47.659049&lon=9.166003'`